# Cant configure robot plugin for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I am using Jenkins (2.289.2) on Linux (OpenSuse).
While i can write pipelines and start robotframework scripts for testing, i am not able to integrate the robot plugin to get logs in Jenkins-style. The robot-logs (log.html, report.html and output.xml) are created, the testrun is executed, success or error for the test-cases are documented.

But here is no sign or whatever that signal that robot-plugin is installed nor a result page from the robot-plugin.

Comment: the plugin only colects and publishes results, it has nothing to do with your ability to run tests. You should be able to see if it is installed under "your jenkins address":"your jenkins port"/pluginManager/installed alternatively you can go to Administration>> manage plugins>> installed plugins

Comment: Excuse me, I was a little bit unclear: I´ve installed all necessary plugin, in the "Plugin Manager" they are shown. I can't get any results other than the robot framework statistics.

Comment: So you cannot add Robot publishing as a post build task, it does not show up in the list?